# Weird database issue in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a strange database problem in django, using sqlite:

In the Model "PrivateMessage":

```
[..]
deleted_from = models.BooleanField(default=False)
[..]
```

In ./manage.py shell

```
In [8]: PrivateMessage.objects.filter(deleted_from=False)
Out[8]: []

In [9]: PrivateMessage.objects.filter(deleted_from=True)
Out[9]: []

In [10]: PrivateMessage.objects.get(id=9).deleted_from
Out[10]: False
```

I could only imagine, that the database is corrupt. Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you try that with various database backends or only sqlite?

Comment: I assume you're not using [custom model managers](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)? Can't think of one which would exhibit this behaviour, but thought I'd check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug with south and sqlite: http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/600

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is some sqlite specific problem, but actually I don't know. Just some idea's what I would do.

You could take a look at the actual SQL query and check if it is correct:

```
# print PrivateMessage.objects.filter(deleted_from=False).query
```

Check what's the values and types of the `deleted_from` model field:

```
# [(m.deleted_from, type(m.deleted_from)) for m in PrivateMessage.objects.all()]
```

Comment: I tried out your first idea, and the query is correct. Your second approach results to: [(False, <type 'bool'>),...